# will React Native 0.60.4 be compatible with ios 13?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I am currently developing a project with react native 0.60.4 and i would like to know if when i build the app **"Final release"** will it be compatible with the lastest version of ios (including ios 13)

**ios 13 ("when it gets released") will be compatible with my app built with react native 0.60.4?**

> my package.json currently have these dependecies

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.4"
```

Comment: I dont know, but if you have an active apple developer license, you should be able to go here and download the beta: https://developer.apple.com/download/ and test your app on it to know for sure.

Comment: I'm on the public beta of iOS 13 and even 0.59 works fine so I think there won't be any problems

Comment: @h-des did you tested it?

Comment: Yes, I'm on public beta 5 and we have many apps on RN 0.59 and no issues so far

Comment: Wow a lot of thanks!